# https websites getting stooped automatically 443 port

Tags: https, cpanel, firewall, configserver

We are using cPanel with CSF Firewall.

The port 443 getting blocked in CSF firewall and all the websites running with https getting stooped automatically.

There is no issue with port 80 and websites running without SSL working fine.

If we restart the CSF firewall, the websites are started working again. But after sometime again facing the same issue.

Comment: I think, this question is not for SO but maybe for Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

You can open ports via `CSF` in `/etc/csf/csf.conf`:

`TCP_IN = "80,443"`

After appending ports you have to execute this command to apply your changes:

`csf -r`